# How can i use vb.net to read and print all html label innerhtml text on a webpage

Tags: html, vb.net, html-agility-pack, innerhtml, label

So i have HTML agility pack.

I am attempting to read a webpage html. I need the contents of a label but am unsure of how to obtain it.

I know what the for attribute is.. but i don't know how to use it to get the innerhtml of the label.

Can anyone help please

```
Private Sub SetTextboxText(ByVal Text As String)
    DirectCast(GetCurrentWebForm.item("frmLogin:strCustomerLogin_userID"), mshtml.HTMLInputElement).value = ""
    DirectCast(GetCurrentWebForm.item("frmLogin:strCustomerLogin_pwd"), mshtml.HTMLInputElement).value = ""
    ClickNormalButton()
    Memorable_Reader()
    End Sub

'Gets and Sets Memorable Information
Private Sub Memorable_Reader()
    'Read Label 'For' Attribute
    'Display Innerhtml Text in msgbox
End Sub

'CLICKS THE SUBMIT BUTTON
Private Sub ClickNormalButton()
    GetCurrentWebForm.submit()
End Sub
```

Update:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://online.lloydsbank.co.uk/personal/logon/login.jsp?WT.ac=PLO0512")
    Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(WebBrowser1.DocumentText)
    Dim labelElement = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//label[@for='frmLogin:strCustomerLogin_userID']")
    Dim labelText = ""
    If labelElement IsNot Nothing Then
        labelText = labelElement.InnerText
    End If

    MsgBox(labelText) <---- Comes out with nothing aka ""
    MsgBox(labelElement.InnerText) <---- same as above
End Sub
```

Comment: Help with what? The code you **didn't** post?

Comment: @JordanHickin would be easier to help you if you post the relevant part of your html, if i understand you you want to get the inner text of something like `<label for="something">Some text</label>` for that you can use xpath as `yourHtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//label[@for='something']").InnerText` that for example will give you the text inside first label found with attribute for of value something, to help you further please post your HTML.

Comment: The html is not my own. The site loads on the webbrowser. So where you have put 'yourHtmlDocument' could i put something like 'webbrowser1.Document'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First look at this simple example:

```
Dim htmlString = "<form><label for='something'>text text</label></form>"
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Dim labelElement = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//label[@for='something']")
Dim labelText = ""
If labelElement IsNot Nothing Then
     labelText = labelElement.InnerText
End If
```

now the `labelText` variable contains `text text`

And here is an example for loading the html from a given link using `WebClient`

```
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Dim webClinet As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim html As String = ""
'add your web page link here
html = webClinet.DownloadString("http://yourlink.com/")
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html)
'and here add your for attribute value for that label instead of something
Dim labelElement =htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//label[@for='something']")
Dim labelText = ""
If labelElement IsNot Nothing Then
    labelText = labelElement.InnerText
End If
```

**Update**:since you said you have it already opened in a `WebBrowser` control use the `DocumentText` property to get the html text as the following:

```
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.DocumentText)
Dim labelElement =htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//label[@for='something']")
Dim labelText = ""
If labelElement IsNot Nothing Then
   labelText = labelElement.InnerText
End If
```

**Update:**Example on how to get Html string from the WebBrowser control

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.com")
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser1.DocumentText)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It comes up saying DocumentText is not a member of webBrowser??

Comment: @JordanHickin it should be [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I found it... For some reason when i start a new project and enter it it is accepted. When i try to enter it into the code i have been working with. a code i found online. it does not. Could Option Strict be the cause?

Comment: @JordanHickin the only thing i can think of is that your old project usese .NET 1.0, go to the Properties of your project and try to change the target framework to at least 2.0

Comment: I am starting to get the label displayed. It is just caught in some loop which is stopping the webpage from loading. But i am sure i can find that :D i will try changing the framework. But thankyou for your help :D